# How to design Acoustical Horn shapes in Blender, using tractrix formula, and exponentials for the flare, as well as circle and elliptical mouths?

Tags: modeling

How to design Acoustical Horn shapes in Blender, using tractrix formula, and exponentials for the flare, as well as circle and elliptical mouths!?

The title pretty much says it all. I have tried to get python to write code, no success there yet. I am not sure how to execute math with the program in order create surfaces.

If one had a tractrix profile of 2d, for example, one could rotate that around a circle to create a circle horn, but what If I wanted the mouth to be elliptical? how to program the transition mathematically?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zz3NbflXZ3A&list=PLXsiVfmTaTKcGqdI0DlWx45BDGiXE-PJD&index=3

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.